# Insert new XML element to existing XML document in JS

Tags: javascript, xml

I am parsing XML via **libxmljs2** and then trying to add an extra element, see example below.

```js
var x = require('libxmljs2');

var xmlDoc = x.parseXmlString(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:FOO xmlns:ns=“example ns" xmlns:ns2="example ns 2”>
   <ns:A>
      <ns2:X>TEXT</ns2:X>
   </ns:A>
   <ns:B>
      <ns2:Y>TEXT</ns2:Y>
      <ns2:Z>TEXT</ns2:Z>
      <ns2:P>TEXT</ns2:P>
   </ns:B>
</ns:FOO>`)
```

What i want is to make it like:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns:FOO xmlns:ns=“example ns" xmlns:ns2="example ns 2">
       <NEW-ELEMENT>
          <NEW-SUB-ELEMENT>
            <ANOTHER-NEW-SUB-ELEMENT>TEXT</ANOTHER-NEW-SUB-ELEMENT>
          <NEW-SUB-ELEMENT>
       </NEW-ELEMENT>
       <ns:A>
          <ns2:X>TEXT</ns2:X>
       </ns:A>
       <ns:B>
          <ns2:Y>TEXT</ns2:Y>
          <ns2:Z>TEXT</ns2:Z>
          <ns2:P>TEXT</ns2:P>
       </ns:B>
    </ns:FOO>
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```js
const reqNode = xmlDoc.get('//ns:FOO', { FOO: 'example'})

const doc = new x.Document();
      doc
          .node('NEW-ELEMENT')
          .node('Service', "TI")
          .parent()
          .node('NEW-SUB-ELEMENT')
            .node('ANOTHER-NEW-SUB-ELEMENT', 'TEXT')
          .parent()
        .parent().toString()
    reqNode.addChild(doc)
```

However it seems to make it like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns:FOO xmlns:ns=“example ns" xmlns:ns2="example ns 2">
       <ns:A>
          <ns2:X>TEXT</ns2:X>
       </ns:A>
       <ns:B>
          <ns2:Y>TEXT</ns2:Y>
          <ns2:Z>TEXT</ns2:Z>
          <ns2:P>TEXT</ns2:P>
       </ns:B>
       <NEW-ELEMENT>
           <NEW-SUB-ELEMENT>
               <ANOTHER-NEW-SUB-ELEMENT>TEXT</ANOTHER-NEW-SUB-ELEMENT>
           <NEW-SUB-ELEMENT>
       </NEW-ELEMENT>
    </ns:FOO>
```

Any ideas, where I'm doing wrong?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node(...)` always adds the node at the end. If you want to insert an element elsewhere you can use [`addPrevSibling(siblingNode)`](https://github.com/marudor/libxmljs2/wiki/Element#elementaddprevsiblingsiblingnode) to insert a node before the Element that was called on. So here you would first find the `ns:A` Element and then call that function on it (you probably have to [construct the child element explicitly](https://github.com/marudor/libxmljs2/wiki/Element#new-libxmlelementdoc-name-content) so it can be passed as an argument).

Comment: Sorry, i'm fairly new to the game. So I would have to find the `<ns:A>`, `addPrevSibling(doc)` on it and then create the rest of the XML document to add as a child?

Comment: `xmlDoc.get('//ns:A', { ns: 'example ns'}).addPrevSibling(doc)` has got the new element in place but has also added the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` tag. Is there anyway to negate adding that tag as part of the building of the new document ?

Comment: The argument to `addPreviousSibling` would be the `NEW-ELEMENT`.

Comment: Regarding the XML header, there probably is an option to not output that somewhere. Please look at the docs and the rest of StackOverflow for that.